# Virtual Host won't run Symfony2

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have `Apache2` installed and I have this setup up on my virtual host pointing out to my symfony project.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName topbesterp
    ServerAlias www.topbesterp.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/topbesterp/web/

    <Directory /var/www/topbesterp/web/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/topbesterp/web/>
         Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have added the codes up at the end of the `apache2.conf`.

And these are the things i added for hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   topbesterp
```

Whenever I run `http://topbesterp` on my browser, I receive a blank page.
But whenever I change the Directory of the virtual host to a project that is non-symfony based, it runs okay. Why?

Comment: Have you added `DirectoryIndex /var/www/topbesterp/web/app.php`? Also, what do the logs tell you?

Comment: I forgot to check the logs. The directory was all okay. Then after I check the logs, i saw that the cahche and logs folder for symfony doesn't have permission. I gave it permission then everythings is all right now. Thanks!

Comment: And what is being shown when you do this: `http://topbesterp/app_dev.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're on LAMP environment so follow the steps below. If MAC then [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/8obp/how-to-set-up-virtual-host-for-symfony-project-in-mac-os).

**1.**

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/topbesterp.local.conf


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName topbesterp.local
    ServerAlias www.topbesterp.local
    ServerAdmin admin@topbesterp.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/topbesterp/web

    <Directory /var/www/topbesterp/web/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/topbesterp.local.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/topbesterp.local.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**2.**

```
sudo a2ensite topbesterp.local.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**3.**

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       topbesterp.local www.topbesterp.local
```

Answer (score -1):

replace `/var/www/topbesterp/web/`

for

```
/var/www/topbesterp/web/app_dev.php
```

or

```
/var/www/topbesterp/web/app_dev.php
```

Answer (score -1):

In fact, you don't specify a directory index in your virtual host, try this to get symfony2 first page (`app_dev.php` is used in development/`app.php` in production) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName topbesterp
ServerAlias www.topbesterp.tld

DocumentRoot /var/www/topbesterp/web

<Directory /var/www/topbesterp/web>
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/topbesterp/web/>
     Options FollowSymlinks
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my comment, you would need to check `app/logs/dev.log` or `app/logs/prod.log`depending on what environment you are running your application.

If you see some writing errors in the cache/logs folder, you'd need to set up the proper permissions to the `app/cache/*` and the `app/logs/*` folders.

[Alternatively, you can add `umask(0000);` at the beginning of the following files:](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup)

- `app/console`
- `web/app_dev.php`
- `web/app.php`

And you'd be good to go.